# lines numbering and formatting

Tags: line-numbers

For practicing in `vim` I made:

```
$ man bash > PracticeFile
```

but upon setting up line numbers, using:

```
:set nu
```

the formatting got messed up, so that letters at the end of line are closer to number than the numbers are to remaining of text.
Is there any way to make line number not interfere with the formatting of the text?

Edit: A screenshot
[image]

Comment: can you provide a screenshot please?

Comment: Btw, try `:help :Man` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lines are just wrapped. To stay in the screen.

If you don't want them wrapped, run:

```
:set nowrap
```

For more information, look at:

```
:help wrap
```

Comment: So there is no other way? some of the text is lost by setting :set nowrap

Comment: What kind of "other way" (other result?) do you think about? It is not lost, you can bring your cursor to the end of the line and the view will scroll to see the right part.

Comment: You are right, that made the trick. I was worried because i am using non GUI tty terminal. Thanks a lot.